# Retrieve a value from a dynamic list of items using jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp, jstl

First of all, I apologize if this is a duplicate question. I couldn't find the exact solution I wanted even though I found similar questions asked.
On my JSP I'm iterating through a list of items as shown below.

```
<c:forEach var="entry" items="${xxx}">
                                <form:form action="XXX.do" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
                                    <!-- other fields -->
                                    <input type="hidden" name="ip" id="ip" value="${entry.ipAddress }" />
                                    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="fun()"/>
                                </form>
</c:forEach>
```

In my jquery function I'm trying to retrieve the value of the hidden field with id 'ip' as shown below:

```
fun() {
    var ip = $('#ip').val();
    //Other stuff
}
```

Now because the hidden field's id is same as 'ip' for all entries in the list, I only retrieve the 'ip' value for the first element in the list. What can I do to get the 'ip' value for the nth element in a dynamically sized list?

Comment: IDs must be _unique_.

Comment: You should use the `class` attribute instead of `id` if there is more than 1 matched element. The `id` is supposed to identify unique elements. Using `class="ip"` and fetching them by `$('.ip').val();` would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method:

> Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

`$("[name='ip']").eq(n)`

or with [`:eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

`$("[name='ip']:eq(n)")`

where `n` is the nth element you're interested in.

**Also, `id`s should be unique. There's no situation where they should be the same.**

Answer (score 1):

The issue with multiple id's aside (you should be using a class), you could do:

```
var ip = $('input[type="hidden"][name="ip"]:nth-child('+n+')').val();
```